# Building Custom Query Filters Lists in Django

Tags: sql, django

I'm building my filters as a list but having trouble building them with the Q function. It seems to be that doing things manually the filters work but when trying to build up the filters by concatenating strings I get the following issues:

Here is the Query:

```
MyLocationFilter = BuildQueryORFilter('MyLocationCountryCode', MyLocationCodePref1)
list = AboutMe.objects.order_by('MyLinkedInLastName').filter(reduce(OR, MyLocationFilter))
```

And here is how I am building those Filters:

```
def BuildQueryORFilter(fieldname, fieldvalues):
    QueryList = []
    spltfieldvalues = fieldvalues.split()
    for item in spltfieldvalues:
        strpitem = item.strip('[],')
        queryitem = Q(fieldname+"__contains="+strpitem)
        QueryList.append(queryitem)
    return QueryList
```

However the problem seems to be how to get Q(..) in the form of `Q(fieldname__contains=gb)` rather than `Q('fieldname__contains=gb')` which seems to be throwing up issues such as:

```
ValueError
Exception Value:    
need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How should I build the Q queries to avoid this unpacking issue?

Traceback for possible answer (below)

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/brett/LinkedIn/phaseone/jelt/views.py" in AboutMeList
  259.  list = AboutMe.objects.order_by('MyLinkedInLastName').filter(MyLocationFilter)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  624.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  642.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1250.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
  1056.         arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /list/
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the keyword argument by unpacking a dict.

```
    strpitem = item.strip('[],')
    key = fieldname + "__contains"
    d = {key: strpitem}
    queryitem = Q(**d)
```

Comment: I tied this, but when printing out queryitem to screen I get: (AND: ('MyLocationCountryCode__contains', u'gb')) and I'm still getting the same issue when trying to filter.

Comment: Is that the traceback when you use the answer I suggested? What is the result of printing the dictionary `d`? There might be a typo in my suggestion, or another mistake in your question that I haven't spotted, but it's definitely closer to the correct solution. It is not possible to pass a single string argument to`Q()`.

Comment: printing the dictionary: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 {'MyLocationCountryCode__contains': u'gb'}

Comment: I can't seem to find a smart way to unpack that dictionary

Comment: I can't spot any other bugs. I would start with something really basic like `d={'MyLocationCountryCode__contains': 'gb'}` and `AboutMe.objects.filter(Q(**d))`, then build up the functionality of your method from there. Good luck!

Comment: Are there any function other than Q you can recommend to test @ the terminal? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Q is a Django library, so at the command prompt **d causes an error. Are there any functions you can recommend that will help: **d
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    **d

Comment: Open up a Django shell with `./manage.py shell`, then test your query there.

Comment: Thanks. Debugging from console was much much better than o/p to browser. Thanks again.